ffmpeg merge audio and video from ytdl-core, outputs an mp4 with no time (no seekable)
i'm trying to merge video and audio from ytdl-core with ffmpeg and export it to user in mp4. The output video apears without time (inifit duration) and can not seek or navigate to another point of the video.
app.get('/downloadmp4', async (req, res)=>{
    let url = req.query.url;
        if (!ytdl.validateURL(url)) {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    let title = 'video';
        let info = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
        title = info.videoDetails.title.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
        res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${title}.mp4"`);

    
          
           let video = ytdl(url,{filter:'videoonly', quality: "highest"})
           let audio = ytdl(url, {filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1<<25});
          
    
        // create the ffmpeg process for muxing
const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(
    ffmpeg,
    [
          '-loglevel', '0', '-hide_banner',
      // input audio by pipe
      "-i", "pipe:3",
  
      // input video by pipe
      "-i", "pipe:4",
  
      // map audio and video correspondingly
      "-map", "0:a",
      "-map", "1:v",
  
      // change the codec
    '-c:v', 'copy',
    '-c:a', 'flac',
    //   "-c:a", "aac",
    '-crf','27',
    "-preset", "veryfast",

    // Allow output to be seekable, which is needed for mp4 output
    '-movflags','frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
  
      // Define output container
      '-f', 'mp4', 'pipe:5',
    ],
    {
      // no popup window for Windows users
      windowsHide: true,
      stdio: [
        // silence stdin/out, forward stderr,
        "inherit", "inherit", "inherit",
        // and pipe audio, video, output
        "pipe", "pipe", "pipe",
      ],
    }
  );
  audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
  video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
  ffmpegProcess.stdio[5].pipe(res);

    })

i tried various formats of video and audio and also the following command '-movflags','frag_keyframe+empty_moov', and the frag_keyframe+faststart without result

Seeking relies on sample tables (stts,stss...) in the moov for each track. These are constructed during muxing and written out at the end. For a normal MP4, ffmpeg needs to seek to the front to either write the sample tables and/or update the media data size. You're piping the output so ffmpeg can't do that. In fragmented mode, the sample tables are empty. All metadata is stored in the fragment boxes, which players don't use for seeking.
Basically, you shouldn't pipe the output.

So, from what i understand from this is that i need to wait until it finish the ffmpeg process and then return the file? how can i wait until the ffmpeg finishes and then return the completed file?
